# Capturando valores com condições múltiplas no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula

Segue abaixo o link de um arquivo do Google Sheets a qual preciso da ajuda de vocês:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ejSffpo56lGFTRHTmueysF3WFZOIP2dO/view?usp=sharing

Existem 2 planilhas nesse arquivo, a planilha de vendas e a planilha de metas.

O que eu preciso é simplesmente pegar a meta que o vendedor bateu de acordo a cada vendedor e a cada categoria.

Não conheço muito de excel e macros, e não consigo achar as palavras corretas pra procurar uma solução na internet, então estou contando com vocês!!

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

não sei se entendi ao certo o que vc quer mas, daria para fazer algo assim
inserir no vendas na coluna E por exemplo a função:

```
=filter(metas!A3:F21;metas!A3:A21=A3;metas!B3:B21=B3;metas!C3:C21<=C3)
```

para referenciar outra planilhas no google sheets usa-se:

O nome da planilha (ou página) seguido do carácter `!`

no seu caso, `metas!`, dessa forma quando vc faz algo como `metas!A3:F21` tera o retorno das celuas da coluda A3 ate a F21 na primeira planilha "metas"

na função filter é preciso varios argumentos, e cada um é separado por `;`.

- o primeiro passado indica o retorno que vc quer. no nossa caso o retorn sera as linhas da planilha vendas.
- os argumentos seguintes indica os critérios do filtro:
- metas!A3:A21=A3 significa que os nomes dos vendedores devem ser iguais em ambas as planilhas
- a seguinte filtra a categoria
- e a seguinte verica se a meta e menor ou igual a venda

isso no google sheets, no excel acho que so muda que em vez do `;` seria `,`
não sei tbm se no excel aceita múltiplos parâmetros.

Comment: Henrique, muito obrigado mas acho que não deixei claro a minha necessidade...
O que eu preciso seria algo assim:

VENDEDOR  |    CATEGORIA     |       BONUS DE META

FERNANDO  |    SEGURANÇA    |       20

Comment: no google sheets tem uma api que ta pra fazer uns scripts que faria de maneira bem mais fácil
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

mas do jeito que vc tafando da pra fazer tbm, mas como nao manjo muito seria meio que uma gabiarra que eu faria

`=SE(maiormeta < venda; "VALOR DESEJADO"; "TESTA OUTRA COISA")`